# Unsure how to take data from one table and move it into another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table:

```
create table practice_table
(
    traffic_date    datetime ,
    door_one        integer ,
    door_two    integer 
)
```

With some sample data:

```
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('12-Oct-2006' ,14500 ,11141)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('13-Oct-2006' ,6804 ,5263)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('14-Oct-2006' ,7550 ,6773)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('15-Oct-2006' ,6144 ,5211)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('16-Oct-2006' ,5680 ,3977)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('17-Oct-2006' ,5199 ,3918)
insert into practice_table(traffic_date, door_one, door_two) values ('18-Oct-2006' ,5298 ,3631)
```

I'm trying to move this into another table (called destination_table) that has the columns:

month (datetime)
traffic_count (integer)

How do I create a loop in SQL to create one row for October in the new table with the total of door_one and door_two without explicitly typing any data in (such as the month)?

Comment: Can you show your sample output?

Comment: I am wondering if it is really necessary to move it to new table. I think you should manage it using View rather than moving it to a new table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a cursor, but if I understand what your trying to do, then it's not necessary.

```
;WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, traffic_date), 0) AS month_field, door_one, door_two
    FROM practice_table
)
INSERT INTO destination_table (month, traffic_count)
SELECT month_field, SUM(door_one + door_two)
FROM tmp
GROUP BY month_field
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't create a loop; you use an INSERT / SELECT combination.

SQL Server 2008:

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table(Month, Traffic_Count)
    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(traffic_date), traffic_date),
           SUM(door_one + door_two)
      FROM Practice_Table
     GROUP BY DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(traffic_date), traffic_date)
```

SQL Server 2012:

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table(Month, Traffic_Count)
    SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(traffic_date), MONTH(traffic_date), 1),
           SUM(door_one + door_two)
      FROM Practice_Table
     GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(traffic_date), MONTH(traffic_date), 1)
```

In both cases, for the sample data, the summary values from October 2006 will all be recorded under the date 2006-10-01 in Destination_Table.

The expressions generate a DATE, which should be converted automatically to [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx), I think.  If not, then you'll need to use DATETIMEFROMPARTS(), presumably, specifying zeroes for the time components.

You might also need to worry about NULLs in the two 'door' columns since your practice table doesn't prohibit them.  If so, then you probably use `SUM(door_one) + SUM(door_two)`.  Aggregates like `SUM` will ignore NULLs (or treat them as zeroes, if you prefer), but if you write `door_one + door_two` and one or the other is NULL, then the result of the addition will be NULL, so effectively one of the non-null values will be ignored.  Doing the aggregates separately avoids this problem.  Generally, I recommend adding NOT NULL everywhere you possibly can, precisely to avoid such gotchas.

Comment: I believe `datefromparts` is not available prior to SQL Server 2012

Comment: @adrift: Oh - thanks for the heads up.  That's the trouble with dealing with dates in SQL; every DBMS has their own system, mutually incompatible.  And yes, it does look like the page Google sent me to is for SQL Server 2012 (despite including 2008 in the search).  So, as I suspected, the DATE calculation needs tweaking by a local SQL Server person; the basic technique is right, but the details of the date calculation are ... inscrutable.  I'd normally write `MDY(MONTH(traffic_date), 1, YEAR(traffic_date))` instead (Informix); same basic idea, just different notation.